# How do I get Checkstyle to ignore final method rule on classes marked with the @Entity annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, checkstyle

Say I have classes marked with the @Entity annotation

```
@Entity
class User {

   public String getName(String name) {
      return this.name;
   }

}
```

Checkstyle will report that the class is not built for extension and suggest marking the methods with final (or the whole class). I can't do this because it's marked as an entity which can't be final.

How do I get Checkstyle to ignore classes marked with @Entity for this rule?

Thanks

Comment: fwiw, not all implementations require non-final classes

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [SuppressionFilter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#Filters) or [SuppressionCommentFilter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#Filters)

> Filter SuppressionFilter rejects audit
>   events for Check errors according to a
>   suppressions XML document in a file.

Comment: I'd rather not add checkstyle specific comments to the java classes or keep a list of classes in an xml file. Or have I misunderstood the filters? Is there a way of modifying the rules or would I have to write my own?

Answer (score 1):

The module you want to disable is [DesignForExtension](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_design.html). Just remove it from your configuration file.

Comment: The problem is I don't want to remove it for every class, only for those marked @Entity

Comment: I actually disabled this check.  In practical sense, I would rather let subclasses try to do whatever they want rather than restrict them and release a patch later to allow for a process I didn't intend originally.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Ant build? If so, in your checkstyle target, try something like:

```
<checkstyle>
    <fileset dir="src.dir">
        <include name="**/*.java" />
        <exclude name="User.java" />
    </fileset>
</checkstyle>
```